# Search for a specific value according to its index

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this

```
[proceedings] => Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [pro_id] => 38
            [doh] => 2019-08-24
            [ndoh] => 2019-08-24
            [stage_id] => 2
            [order_sheet] => 
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [pro_id] => 38
            [doh] => 2019-08-24
            [ndoh] => 2019-08-28
            [stage_id] => 108
            [order_sheet] => order sheet
        )

)
```

I have a value '2019-08-24' like it, and I want to search the value according to on my `[doh]` key in my complete array how can I tried many ways but it wouldn't help.

I want to match the value of `[doh]` in all the arrays indexes

Comment: So have you tried a `foreach()` and checked each value of `doh`?

Comment: yes i tried but i am little but confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But your `foreach()` should work, if you property compare it with `$doh` value,

```
$doh='2019-08-24';
$array = [
  (object)  ['pro_id' => 38,'doh' => '2019-04-24','ndoh' => '2019-05-24','stage_id' => 2,'order_sheet' =>'oder sheet'] ,
  (object)  ['pro_id' => 30,'doh' => '2019-08-24','ndoh' => '2019-08-24','stage_id' => 3,'order_sheet' =>'oder sheet'] ,
];
foreach($array as $obj) {
    if ($doh == $obj->doh) {
        $entry[] = $obj;
    }
}
print_r($entry);
```

With `array_filter()`,

```
<?php
$array = [
  (object)  ['pro_id' => 38,'doh' => '2019-04-24','ndoh' => '2019-05-24','stage_id' => 2,'order_sheet' =>'oder sheet'] ,
  (object)  ['pro_id' => 30,'doh' => '2019-08-24','ndoh' => '2019-08-24','stage_id' => 3,'order_sheet' =>'oder sheet'] ,
];

$doh='2019-08-24';
$entry = array_filter($array, function($e) use($doh) { return $e->doh==$doh; });
print_r($entry);
```

Answer (score 1):

Or You can use `array_filter()`

```
<?php
$a_proceedings = Array
(
    (object) array(
            'pro_id' => '38',
            'doh' => '2019-08-24',
            'ndoh' => '2019-08-24',
            'stage_id' => 2,
            'order_sheet' => '',
        ),

    (object) array
        (
            'pro_id' => 38,
            'doh' => '2019-08-24',
            'ndoh' => '2019-08-28',
            'stage_id' => 108,
            'order_sheet' => 'order sheet',
        )

);

var_dump(array_filter($a_proceedings, function($elem) {
    return $elem->doh == '2019-08-24';
}));
```